# Everyplay Unity iOS recording broken with anti-aliasing off

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, everyplay

I got the latest Everyplay Unity iOS integration (v1.7.6) from github and discovered a bug.

If I turn off anti-aliasing from in Unity quality setting, the moment I call start recording, the screen stops updating, even though I can hear the game running (because the sound still playing).

If I re-enable anti-aliasing, the recording function as normal.

I am planning to not enable AA in my game.

Answer (score 0):

So far the Unity plugin side has been pretty lightweight but there's more C# and better integration in the works.

Most times, updating just Everyplay.framework is sufficient since there are no graphics changes in the plugin. With 1.7.6, there's a transition going on to a new graphics integration, which is used by default when compiling against recent enough SDK, otherwise
it's falling back to old integration.

So it's important to know if the latest plugin has also been re-imported to the project
and in some cases graphics bugs are bound to be Unity version specific (version info missing)

Please feel free to send more information or potential test case triggering the issue to support at everyplay com

UPDATE:

It seems both 1.7.5/1.7.6 SDK's using the new graphics integration used in the latest Unity package have a regression when dealing with custom sizes through Screen.SetResolution().

This has been fixed to the next release following 1.7.6, thanks!

As a workaround, keep the device resolution as native or modify
`Assets/Plugins/iOS/EveryplayGlesSupport.mm` to always build with
`ENABLE_GLES_WRAPPER` enabled

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am using Unity 4.3.4. Last night I upgraded to 1.7.6, Unity integration + framework bundle. When the bug occurs, I also see continous error output in XCode console coming from GlesHelper.mm with an error code (which I don't remember at this point, will check tonight).